# Is there any difference between "Vermögensteuer" and "Vermögenssteuer"?

Tags: grammar

In **Reiche bereiten sich auf die Vermögensteuer vor**, [Vermögensteuer](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/finanzen/meine-finanzen/steuern-sparen/angst-vor-rot-gruenen-steuerplaenen-reiche-bereiten-sich-auf-die-vermoegensteuer-vor-12285544.html) is spelt with a single **-s-**. But in the online dictionary that I use, the word is spelt with a double **-ss-**: [Vermögenssteuer](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/verm%C3%B6genssteuer).

Is this not the same word (*wealth tax*)? If it is the same word, meaning the same thing, why the different spelling? Or is it yet another mistake in the German press that I've (quite) unwittingly unearthed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duden lists both as possible spellings:

> [Vermögensteuer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vermoegensteuer)
>
> [Vermögenssteuer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vermoegenssteuer)

with the same meaning:

> Steuer, die nach jemandes Vermögen (2) bemessen wird und bei der das Vermögen Gegenstand der Besteuerung ist

---

The wikipedia page uses [`Vermögenssteuer`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verm%C3%B6gensteuer) though.

Wiktionary uses [`Vermögenssteuer`](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verm%C3%B6genssteuer) but lists `Vermögensteuer` as an alternative spelling.

BWT: [Here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) are some details about the usage of `Fugenlaut`.

---

I myself would use `Vermögenssteuer` and haven't heard `Vermögensteuer` so far...

---

**Edit**: Comparison on television/news sites (source: google search results):

```
 --------------------------------------------------
| Site          | Vermögensteuer | Vermögenssteuer |
| zdf.de        |        38      |       364       |
| ard.de        |         7      |      1130       |
| heute.de      |        45      |        57       |
| tagesschau.de |        95      |       583       |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Danke. If I'm not asking too much, could you please provide me with a rough translation of the sentence? (I haven't been able to find the (probable) verb _*vorreichen_, and I don't know if _bereiten_ means _to prepare_, _to make up_ or _to cause_.

Comment: If you are asking for a translation of: _"Reiche bereiten sich auf die Vermögensteuer vor"_: It's something like: _"The rich prepare themselves for wealth tax."_ An alternative would be: _"The rich brace themselves for wealth tax."_

Comment: So the actual verb I should have been looking for was _vorbereiten_. And _Reiche_ means _rich man_. That's what happens when you're still a beginner in the language. I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

When searching the official page from the [German ministery of finance](http://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de) we can find both, *"Vermögensteuer"*, and *"Vermögenssteuer"* but the first is far more often used:

> Google site search on `site:http://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de`
>
> - **"Vermögensteuer"**: 566 results
> - **"Vermögenssteuer"**: 37 results

This indicates that both terms may be correct. If in doubt we may be on the safe side to use *"Vermögensteuer"* in an official context. In all other instances we may want to use the grammatically better *"Vermögens**s**teuer"*.

Comment: So these online dictionaries should really be updated or something, right?

Comment: Not really. From a linguistic view *"Vermögenssteuer"* feels much better (genitive case!) but we can't close our eyes to  people who invented this tax ;)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut): _die offizielle Benennung von Steuern erfolgt in Deutschland im Gegensatz zu Österreich und der Schweiz ohne Fugen-s._ I wouldn't follow this quirk unless writing an official text.

Answer (score 2):

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut#Verwendung tells us that legal terms usually use the Fugen-s, but the names of taxes don't (except for Austria and Switzerland). So the variant without the Fugen-s is the official one, but the one with is the more common one in everyday speech. Both are correct and have identical meaning.

Comment: Was es nicht alles gibt: Unterschiede in der Amt(s)- und Recht(s)sprache! Sehr schön.