# 'Violinunterricht' vs. 'Violinenunterricht'?

Tags: compound

I always thought that the correct way to say this was "Violinenunterricht." However, it seems that "Violinunterricht" is more commonly used (there are also more hits on Google). Which one is correct and why? Is there a rule about this and is this comparable to the "Gedichtanalyse" vs. "Gedichtsanalyse" question? What is the formal term for this kind of construction?

Comment: Both are less common than "Geigenunterricht", at least in informal context. (google.at gives me ~200.000 hits for *Geigenunterricht*, ~18.000 for *Violinenunterricht*, ~50.000 for *Violinunterricht*)

Answer (score 2):

This is a question about Fugenlaute (according joints) that are used as joiner between the parts of compound words.

Compound words are very often used in German Language, and so you very often have to decide which Fugenlaut to use. The problem ist, that the rules are very variable.

### Violinenunterricht

Very often the Fugenlaut is chosen that way, that the first part together with the Fugenlaut is equal to the plural or genitiv of the first part. In the case of »Violinenunterricht« you see such a plural-like construction, but it is not really a plural. It is just the first part »Violine« joint with a »n« that comes not from the plural, but just is a Fugenlaut.

### Violineunterricht

Sometimes you omit any Fugenlaut like in *Haustür*, *Tischdecke* or *Gasthaus*. You can use this kind of joining also for Violine and Unterricht.

### Violinunterricht

Here the e at the end of *Violone* has been omitted. This happens sometimes when a word that ends with an e is joint with a word that starts with a vowel, but is rarely done.

All three variations (Violinenunterricht, Violineunterricht and Violinunterricht) are correct German words.

### some other facts about Fugenlaute

As said before, rules for Fugenlaute are not very clear, and so you often find more then just one solution for joining two words. Especially there are different rules in Germany and in Austria. I give you some examples:

**Advent + Kalender**
In Germany: Adventskalender (with an s between the parts)
In Austria: Adventkalender (no Fugenlaut)

**Schwein + Braten**
In Germany (without Bavaria): Schweinebraten (e)
In Austria and Bavaria: Schweinsbraten (s)

**Schaden + Ersatz**
In Germany: Schadensersatz (s)
In Austria: Schadenersatz (-)

**Einkommen + Steuer**
In Germany: Einkommensteuer (-)
In Austria: Einkommenssteuer (s)

You find more Information about Fugenlaute here:

[Fugenkonsonanten bei zusammengesetzten Wörtern](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5253/fugenkonsonanten-bei-zusammengesetzten-w%c3%b6rtern)
[Welche grammatische Form kann das erste Wort in zusammengesetzen Wörtern annehmen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/942/welche-grammatische-form-kann-das-erste-wort-in-zusammengesetzen-w%c3%b6rtern-annehme)
[Is there any difference between "Vermögensteuer" and "Vermögenssteuer"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7290/is-there-any-difference-between-verm%c3%b6gensteuer-and-verm%c3%b6genssteuer)

and

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut)

Comment: Hubert, now you are making an equivalent mistake you accused others of in other questions: it is plainly wrong that in Germany one says eg "Schweinebraten". For once, there are certainly some Austrians around who will not change the way they speak just because they are in Germany. But seriously, "Schweinebraten" is pretty much unheard of at least in Bavaria, presumably in most parts of southern Germany - certainly accounting for a non-negligable percentage of the population.

Comment: @Gerhard: I edited the Schwein-s/e-braten-Section. Is it ok now?

Comment: I was really referring to all examples - although I know people using both forms for the latter two. Anyway, I know what you meant of course, and I don't think there is a way to be exact without making it so complicated that no-one can follow or so general that it becomes meaningless.

Comment: @Gerhard kenne mich überhaupt nicht gut aus, bin sogar Ausländer, aber AdA bietet auf seiner Hompage drei Graphiken. Und die sind auch in [meiner Antwort](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/22492/1691) zu finden

Comment: ... aber *Violinsunterricht* sagt doch hoffentich niemand, oder?

Comment: @gerhard... I'm from Berlin and for me Schweinebraten is perfectly normal and the other options sound wrong.

Comment: Schweinebraten ist vollkommen in Ordnung; das habe ich im ganzen Leben so gehört und verwendet.

Comment: @MartinPeters: Aber eben nicht in Österreich. Wenn du in einem Altwiener Gasthaus (oder auch in Graz, Klagenfurt usw.) einen Schweinebraten (mit e) bestellst, outest du dich sofort als Tourist oder Immigrant aus Deutschland. Wobei anzumerken ist, dass ich sogar schon meine eigene Frau (gebürtige Wienerin, hat aber viele Arbeitskollegen, die aus Deutschland nach Österreich eingewandert sind) »Schweinebraten (mit e)« sagen gehört habe. Gängig und als »normal« empfunden wird - zumindest in den östlichen Bundesländern Österreichs - aber weiterhin der Schweinsbraten mit s.

Comment: @Takkat: Nein, *Violinsunterricht* sagt (hoffentlich) tatsächlich niemand, denn das wäre auch falsch. Der Singular lautet nämlich nicht *Violin* sondern *Violine*. Um zu *Violins* zu kommen, müsste man das *e* weglassen (was, wie erwähnt ohnehin nur in Ausnahmefällen passiert), und dann noch als zusätzlichen zweiten Schritt ein *s* einfügen. Ich glaube nicht, dass jemand ernsthaft auf die Idee kommt, das zu tun.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast Ich glaube gerne, daß es in Österreich so ist.