# Schadenfall vs Schadensfall

Tags: genitive, reformed-orthography

In einem Versicherungspapier bin ich über den Begriff *Schadenfall* gestolpert und war mir zu 90% sicher, dass die Schreibweise falsch ist. Meiner Intuition nach müsste zwingend ein Genitiv-s eingefügt werden nach dem Schema:

> Im Fall eines Schadens   -> Im Schadensfall

Der Duden belehrte mich jedoch eines Besseren. Tatsächlich sind [*Schadensfall*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schadensfall) und [*Schadenfall*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schadenfall) beides zulässige Schreibweisen. Im selben Text fand ich auch [*Versicherungsteuer*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Versicherungsteuer), bei dem sich mir die Fingernägel hochrollen, das aber laut Duden korrekt ist. Nach welcher Regel oder Logik werden diese Formen ohne Genitiv-s gebildet? Ist das eine dieser berüchtigten Verschlimmbesserungen der neuen Rechtschreibregeln?

Comment: Nein, es ist Amt[s]deutsch ohne Regeln, ohne Logik. Bastian Sick hat in der Zwiebelfischkolumne einen [launigen Beitrag](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-bratskartoffeln-und-spiegelsei-a-293186.html) dazu geschrieben und einen Überblick über den [Gebrauch des Fugen-s](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-der-gebrauch-des-fugen-s-im-ueberblick-a-293195.html) gegeben.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7290/is-there-any-difference-between-verm%c3%b6gensteuer-and-verm%c3%b6genssteuer

Comment: Das ist kein Genitiv-s sondern ein ein Fugen-s.

Comment: Und wieder: Der Duden ist nicht für die Korrektheit zuständig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das ist ein so genannter [Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut#Distribution) bei zusammen gesetzten Substantiven. Es gibt leider keine eindeutigen Regeln dafür, als das was sich im Sprachgebrauch "eingebürgert" hat. Es gibt eine Menge von möglichen Fugenlauten, da in der Deutschen Sprache Zusammensetzungen stark verbreitet sind: -e-, -s-, -es-, -n-, -en-, -er-, -ens-. Eine Weglassung wird übrigens eine Nullmorphem genannt.

Comment: Wenn wir schon bei Zusammensetzungen sind: _sogenannter_ und _zusammengesetzten_.

Comment: Es gibt auch innerhalb der Deutschen Sprache regionale Variationen - Die Schweizer sagen *Schnellzug**s**wagen*, was in Deutschland jedem komisch vorkommt.

Comment: Vergleiche auch 'Schweinsbraten' (süddt./bairisch) und 'Schweinebraten' (norddt.).