# Wann braucht ein zusammengesetztes Wort ein "s" in der Mitte, wann nicht?

Tags: compound

Nehmen wir an, dass man ein zusammengesetztes Wort aus zwei anderen Wörten bilden will, z.B. aus "Winter" und "Leere". Dann könnte man "Wintersleere" oder "Winterleere" schreiben.   Mein Lehrer hat mir angedeutet, dass "Wintersleere" inkorrekt ist, demnach nehme ich an, dass es "Winterleere" sein soll.  Wie würde man dass von vornherein wissen?  Anderes Beispiel ist "Ausgang" + "Punkt": Ich weiß schon, dass es "Ausgangspunkt" ist.  Aber hier haben wir ein zusätzliches "S", das meines Erachtens als possessiv wirkt.  Gibt es einen Weg zu bestimmen, ob man ein zusätzliches "S" bei der Bildung zusammengesetzter Wörter benutzen soll oder nicht?

EDIT: (Es scheint, dass es eine [ähnliche Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/42073/schadenfall-vs-schadensfall) gibt, und mir wurde empfohlen, meine Frage zu schließen.  Aber ich glaube, dass diese jetzige Diskussion ziemlich ausführlicher ist, im Vergleich zu der anderen Frage, also glaube ich, dass meine Frage aktiv bleiben soll)

Comment: Wenn irgendjemand das mal verwursten will: https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/korpusgrammatik/4697

Comment: @DavidVogt: siehe meine Beitrag - ich halte das für von Vornherein unmöglich und das "Ergebnis" für maschinell erlernten Humbug.

Comment: @bakunin Wie kann man eigentlich sein Gefühl über die Ergebnisse der monatelangen Arbeit von Sprachwissenschaftlern stellen? (Und das, nachdem man sich nicht mehr als fünf Minuten mit dieser Arbeit befaßt hat.)

Comment: @DavidVogt Der verlinkte Artikel beschreibt eigentlich auch nicht viel mehr, als der Maschine "das Gefühl" beizubringen (indem man ihr möglichst viele Beispiele zeigt). Ob es dann in irgendeiner Weise mehr legitim ist, *daraus* eine  Regel abzuleiten, als es gleich "nach Gefühl" zu machen, halte ich für sehr zweifelhaft und eigentlich für einen sehr verwirrten Zirkelschluß.

Comment: Wir können natürlich auch immer weiter die gleichen Beispiele *Schweinebraten, Schweinsbraten* wiederholen ([seit 2011](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/942/welche-grammatische-form-kann-das-erste-wort-in-zusammengesetzen-w%c3%b6rtern-annehme)).

Comment: @DavidVogt: erstens weißt Du nicht, wie lange ich mich mit der Arbeit beschäftigt habe, zweitens habe ich nicht auf mein "Gefühl" rekurriert (das ich gar nicht erwähnt habe) und drittens habe ich auf meinen Beitrag verwiesen, in dem ich - anz ohne Gefühl - begründet habe, warum es meiner Meinung nach keine *konsistenten* Regeln gibt. Ich kann mit beliebig leistungsfähigen Computern Nonsens produzieren und der Umstand, daß ich keine Eier legen kann, hindert mich nicht daran, zu erkennen, wenn eins faul ist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schadenfall vs Schadensfall](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/42073/schadenfall-vs-schadensfall)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leider gibt es nicht nur keine Regel, wann welcher Fugenlaut einzusetzen ist, sondern es besteht im deutschen Sprachraum auch durchaus Uneinigkeit darüber, wann das überhaupt der Fall ist: was in Deutschland *Advent-s-kranz* heißt, wird in Österreich *Adventkranz* genannt. Auch darüber, ob es "Schwein-s-braten" oder "Schwein-e-braten" heißt, herrscht Uneinigkeit zwischen den Ländern im deutschen Sprachgebiet. Für Schnitzel vom Schwein gilt Analoges.

Zwar wissen die Deutschen besser, was genau ein "Wiener Schnitzel" ist, als die Wiener selber (denen es vor einem zentimeterdicken Kalbschnitzel, das mit Pommes Frites anstatt lauwarmem Erdäpfelsalat serviert wird, eher graust), aber ob das jetzt "Rindschnitzel" oder "Rindsschnitzel" heißt, "Kalbsschnitzel" oder "Kalbschnitzel", das ist keineswegs klar. Ich habe schon beide Varianten gesehen.

Es gibt die *Schiffahrt* und die *Schiffsfahrt*, wobei letzteres "s" wohl eher ein Marker für den Genitiv ist.

Tatsächlich ist nicht einmal das Aufeinandertreffen gleicher Konsonanten konsistent geregelt, denn während das "Handtuch" so heißt, braucht die Gegend "Hundsturm" (ein Teil des 5. Wiener Gemeindebezirks) ein Fugen-s.

Comment: Das heißt aber in Summe auch, dass man nicht sehr viel falsch machen kann....

Comment: @bakunin Von einem rein logischen Standpunkt gesehen, _muss_ es sogar eine Funktion geben, die das modelliert. Wenn man ein Machine-Learning-Model hat, das auf einer Teilmenge trainiert ist und die anderen Einträge, auf denen es nicht trainiert wurde, überzufällig gut vorhersagt, dann ist das ein empirischer Beleg dafür, dass in dem Modell ein Verständnis der tatsächlich zugrundeliegenden Funktion enthalten ist. Dass die Funktion zu komplex ist, um auf den ersten Blick erkannt zu werden, oder dass die Parameter der Funktion nicht (vollständig) bekannt sind, widerspricht dem ja nicht.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: siehe oben, den Kommentar von tofro. Da sich nicht mal diejenigen, die deutsch sprechen, einig darüber sind, ob an bestimmten Stellen "s", "e", oder sonstwas hineingehört oder nicht, kann die Maschine auch keine Regel ableiten. Oder füttert man der Maschine ein Kompositum und die sagt dann: "das wird dort so und da anders gesprochen"? *Das* würde ich in der Tat für einen Erfolg halten, aber es erscheint mir eher unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Ich denke, hier auf "künstliche Intelligenz" zu setzen, um eine Regel zu finden, ist volkommen das falsche Pferd. "Künstliche Intelligenz" tendiert eher dazu, Regeln zu *verwischen* als sie zu finden (das Verwischen findet dadurch statt, dass Regeln sich in Atttraktor- und Distraktorfaktoren z.B. eines neuronalen Netzes verstecken und, nachdem man das Netz lange genug trainiert hat, zwar die Regeln "angewendet" werden, aber nicht mehr explizit auffindbar sind....

Comment: ...Anzunehmen, dass es ein neuronales Netz gibt, dass eine solche Funktion berechnen kann, ist auch ein Trugschluss - Es gibt durchaus neuronale Netze, die so instabil sind, dass sie mit jedem neuen Beispiel, das man ihnen gibt, komplett kippen und "ihre Meinung ändern". Ein Netz muss nicht unbedingt automatisch zu irgendeinem stabilen Zustand konvergieren. Es ist nur ein schöner Zufall, wenn es das tut und möglicherweise ein Hinweis darauf, dass es tatsächlich eine zugrundeliegende Regel bgeben könnte.

Comment: @tofro: Dein eigenes Gehirn ist auch ein neuronales Netz. Wenn du neuronalen Netzen prinzipiell die Fähigkeit abzusprichst, implizite Regeln abzuleiten um sie später anwenden zu können, dann sprichst du dir selbst die Fähigkeit ab, irgendetwas zu erlernen. Die Tatsache, dass es instabile neuronale Netze gibt, bedeutet einerseits, dass diese konkreten Netze schlecht konzipiert wurden, und andererseits sind manche Menschen da nicht viel anders. Die Meinung zu ändern, wenn neue Fakten bekannt werden, ist das, was Wissenschaft von Religion unterscheidet.

Comment: Wenn man [Vorhersage von Fugenelementen in nominalen Komposita](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/korpusgrammatik/4697) liest, sieht man, daß keine neuronalen Netzwerke zum Einsatz kamen. Mit Komposita mit variablem Fugenelement kann man umgehen: Wird mindestens eine Variante vorhergesagt, zählt es als richtige Vorhersage.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ja, das Gehirn ist "eine Art neuronales Netz", aber um so viele Größenordnungen komplexer als heutige Computer, daß wir es effektiv als etwas anderes betrachten müssen. Hegels Zweiter Hauptsatz der Dialektik (Umschlag von Quantitäten in neue Qualitäten) wurde nicht aus Langeweile formuliert. Der menschliche Körper ist auch "eine Art Verbrennungsmotor", weil Stoffwechselvorgänge auf Oxydation beruhen, trotzdem ist zwischen einem Arzt und einem Automechaniker ein Unterschied.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Wenn die Vorhersage "wenigstens eine[r] Variante" schon als "richtig zählt", dann habe ich soeben ein Programm zur Vorhersage aller künftigen Lottoziehungen geschrieben: es spuckt einfach einen Haufen Zufallszahlen zwischen 1-49 aus und wenn auch nur eine richtig war, dann wurde die Ziehung erfolgreich vorhergesagt. Ich frage mich, ob ich dieses bahnbrechende Ergebnis publizieren sollte.

Comment: @bakunin: Ich habe nicht geschrieben »Dein eigenes Gehirn ist auch **eine Art** neuronales Netz«. Ich habe geschrieben »Dein eigenes Gehirn ist auch **ein** neuronales Netz«. Ich schrieb nicht »etwas in der Art« sondern »ganz genau dasselbe«. Das, was »eine Art neurales Netz« (also etwas ähnliches, aber nicht genau dasselbe) ist, ist beispielsweise ChatGPT, denn das ist ein LLM (Large Language Model). Aber tofro sprach nicht von ChatGPT oder von einem LLM, sondern von einem neuronalen Netz, also von genau dem Typ, zu dem auch biologische Gehirne gehören.

Comment: (Fortsetzung:) Das menschliche Gehirn besteht aus ungefähr 100 Milliarden Neuronen. GPT-4 (die leistungsstärkere der Maschinen, die man bei ChatGPT auswählen kann) verfügt - je nachdem, wen man fragt - über 1,8 bis 100 Milliarden Parameter, wobei ich persönlich die 1,8 Mrd für glaubhafter halte. Aber selbst bei dieser Zahl ist die Komplexität von ChatGPT keineswegs um »viele Größenordnungen« kleiner als die eines menschlichen Gehirns. Ich erwarte, dass es noch in diesem Jahrzehnt künstliche Intelligenzen geben wird, die nachweislich komplexer als menschliche Gehirne sein werden.

Answer (score 3):

Es geht ja nicht nur darum, ob ein S in die Nahtstelle im Wort Advent?kranz oder Zug?führer gehört, sondern manchmal auch darum, ob ein E oder ein S in den Schwein?braten gehört, oder darum, ob man der Speise?karte noch ein N gönnen soll. Und dann stellt sich noch die Frage, warum ein Kind?kopf die Bedeutung wechselt, wenn man ER durch S ersetzt. In denselben Themenkreis gehört auch die Frage, warum die Krone und im Kronprinz ihr E verliert, aber in der Kronenzeitung ein N angehängt bekommt. (Die Kronenzeitung ist eine österr. Boulevardzeitung, vergleichbar mit der Bild-Zeitung in Deutschland.) Ebenso Seelsorger - Seelenruhe.

Es ist auch unklar, woher die Fugenlaute überhaupt kommen. Manche sagen, sie wären die Pluralform des ersten Wortes, andere Theorien gehen von einer Genitivbildung aus. Aber wenn man beispielsweise versucht herauszufinden, wo das S in der Religionsfreiheit herkommt, wird man erkennen müssen, dass die Fugenlaute eine separate Kategorie sind, die möglicherweise zwar von anderen grammatikalischen Abwandlungsvarianten von Wortbestandteilen beeinflusst sind, aber als eigenständiges Phänomen zu behandeln sind. (Im Fall der Religionsfreiheit greift nicht einmal die Idee, dass der Fugenlaut die Aussprache vereinfacht, denn in den Konsonantencluster *nfr* noch einen vierten Konsonanten zu quetschen, macht gar nichts einfacher.)

Man kann anhand des Kontexts erkennen, ob man von einem Kindskopf (einer Person, die sich kindisch benimmt) oder einem Kinderkopf (Körperteil eines Kindes) reden soll. Aber um zu entscheiden, ob man von einem Schweinebraten (D) oder einem Schweinsbraten (Ö) reden soll, braucht man die geographische Information. Ebenso beim Haltverbot (D), Halteverbot (Ö), Schadenersatz (D), Schadensersatz (Ö), dem schon erwähnten Adventskalender (D), Adventkalender (Ö) und vielen weitern Wörtern. In der Schweiz hat die Bahnhofhalle kein S, in D und Ö aber schon, und den Schweizern ist auch ein Schweinsbraten lieber als ein Schweinebraten (auch: Rinderbraten nur in D, aber Rindsbraten in Ö und CH).

Aber auch innerhalb Deutschlands ist nicht immer alles einheitlich. Die Speisekarte ist weit verbreitet, aber in einigen Regionen liegt in den Gaststätten eher eine Speisenkarte auf den Tischen.

Die genannten Beispiele sind lauter häufig verwendete Wörter, die man in Wörterbüchern nachschlagen kann. Bei ihnen haben sich bestimmte Fugenlaute etabliert, aber eben nicht in allen Regionen des deutschen Sprachraums dieselben. Das Machine-Learning-Modell, das Jonathan Scholbach in [seinem Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76302/wann-braucht-ein-zusammengesetztes-wort-ein-s-in-der-mitte-wann-nicht#comment181269_76303) zur [Antwort von bakunin](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/76303/1487) erwähnt hat, müsste also nicht nur wie sonst üblich einfach eine Menge Texte analysieren, um daraus den Regelsatz für Fugenlaute abzuleiten, sondern es bräuchte zusätzlich zum Text auch die Information, in welcher geographischen Region dieser Text entstanden ist. Und um dann einen Text auch korrekt erzeugen zu können, müsste dieses Modell dann auch wissen, in welcher Region der Text verwendet werden soll.

Wenn man dann den Fugenlaut für ein neuartiges Kompositum wie die *Winter?leere* erraten muss, wird es schwierig. Soll man sich an der [Winterszeit](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Winterszeit) orientieren, die ein S enthält, oder an der [Winterzeit](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Winterzeit), die ohne S auskommt? Außer der Winterszeit kommen alle Komposita mit *Winter* ohne S aus (Winterpause, Winterreifen, Wintermantel, Winterlager, Winterluft), daher ist es vermutlich nicht falsch, bei der Winterleere auch darauf zu verzichten, aber eben die *Winterszeit* belegt, dass das nicht zwingend so sein muss.

---

Fazit: Es gibt natürlich implizite Regeln, die angewendet werden, um die richtigen Fugenlaute zu finden. Zu diesen Regeln gehören aber unzählige Ausnahmen, und sie sind auch über den deutschen Sprachraum hinweg nicht einheitlich. Es gibt auch Versuche, diese impliziten Regeln explizit zu machen, also niederzuschreiben. Aber die Verwendung von Fugenlauten nach diesen expliziten Regeln zu lernen, ist wie Klavierspielen lernen indem man Lehrbücher über das Klavierspielen liest, ohne jemals ein Klavier anzufassen. Man muss die deutsche Sprache lange und ausgiebig verwenden, um mit den Fugenlauten einigermaßen gut klarzukommen, aber wenn man dann in eine andere deutschsprachige Region übersiedelt, muss man vieles wieder neu lernen.

Comment: Ich (D) stelle staunend fest, dass Wikipedia das [Haltverbot](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haltverbot) kennt, begegnet ist mir nur das *Halteverbot*.